# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Tags: macos, swift3

I got this error on my code :

```
func getBatteryInfos(){
    let snapshot = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo().takeRetainedValue()

    // Pull out a list of power sources
    let sources = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList(snapshot).takeRetainedValue() as Array

    // For each power source...
    for ps in sources {
        // Fetch the information for a given power source out of our snapshot
        let info = IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription(snapshot, ps).takeUnretainedValue() as Dictionary

        // Pull out the capacity
        if let

            capacity = info[kIOPSCurrentCapacityKey] as? Double, //Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'
             let charging = info[kIOPSIsChargingKey] as? Int{ //Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

                batteryPercentage = capacity
                batteryState = charging

                print("Current battery percentage \(batteryPercentage)")
                print("Current state \(batteryState)")



        }
    }
```

I tried to replace `info[kIOPSCurrentCapacityKey]` with `info["kIOPSCurrentCapacityKey"]` but the same error occurs.
I saw a few questions about this error on StackOverflow but all the answers are not working with my code.

I'm working with Xcode 8 Beta 6 and Swift3. In Swift 2, this code worked perfectly.

Any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot cast to a typeless Swift dictionary or array. Change

```
as Dictionary
as Array
```

to

```
as NSDictionary
as NSArray
```

Or, if you know the actual types (i.e. what is this an array *of*? what is this a dictionary *of?*), cast down to those actual types.

Another approach is to use the new untyped types, `[Any]` and `[AnyHashable:Any]`. But this can be a little tricky, in my experience. Basically Apple has blown away the automatic bridging between Objective-C and Swift and replaced it with "permissive boxing", and this causes some type mismatches that you have to compensate for yourself.

Comment: I can't test this because I don't know the types you are using (I have no idea what a IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo is, for example), so you will have to experiment and possibly tweak in order to get this right. For example, you might need `as!` instead of `as`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, adding NS before Dictionary and Array did the trick. Do you think Apple broke the automatic bridging for more precision and security ?

Comment: You may draw your own conclusions. :) https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0072-eliminate-implicit-bridging-conversions.md

Answer (score 0):

I found this

I got same problem

```
    if let paymentDict = dict["payment"] as? Dictionary
    {
        self.payment = OrderPayment(dict: paymentDict)
    }
```

then I add more specific type of Dictionary

```
    if let paymentDict = dict["payment"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
    {
        self.payment = OrderPayment(dict: paymentDict)
    }
```

It's works for me